# How to avoid getting 'Missing File' error in Photos app?

Tags: mac, photos.app

I get the following error in Photos app on my Mac.

```
Missing File
Photos with unavailable original files cannot be opened.
The original photo “IMG_3076.JPG” is either offline or cannot be found. Click “Find Original” to reconnect.
```

This is what has happened, I assumed that since the photo is in the Photo Library I could delete the file from the hard drive. Apparently not. The reason I deleted the files was to avoid duplication and save disk space. When I right click and look at the info for the photo, I see that the size and dimensions of the image are same as the original file. So I am really not precious about the file being there.

So I have the following questions.

1. How do I prevent Photo app from showing this error?
2. Will I be able to export these files and edit them as normal?

Here is screenshot of Photos app preferences
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether the file was actually duplicated...

From Photos prefs

[image]

If you have that pref set, then the original becomes redundant once imported, as Photos now refers to its saved internal copy as the 'original'.

If unchecked, then the original remains where it was on your drive & if deleted can no longer be found by Photos [or indeed anything else, as it really no longer exists.]

If that option hasn't always been checked, then some files will still be externally referenced & need to be copied to the Library before they can be finally discarded from their original locations.

The way to achieve this will be to initially return all those files you discarded to the locations Photos expects them to be.

The you can use File Menu > Consolidate, which will copy all those external references into the Photos Library.

Once this is complete, then you can finally discard the external files safely.

Comment: but how does the photo show up if the file is missing? Photos is able to show me the image, i can see its size etc....

Comment: It's in the database, likely with a thumbnail. tbh, I've never actually tried 'breaking' it just to see what happens.

Comment: I have updated the question with the screenshot of my preferences and can confirm that the said option is selected. Now, how do I get rid of the error message?

Comment: Check the File menu - is the option 'Show referenced file in Finder' available or greyed? I'm wondering if it does in fact think the original is still external. BTW, Pro tip for screen captures of windows, Cmd/shift/4 then tap spacebar & click the window you need. That captures the window itself & adds a nice drop-shadow.

Comment: The 'Show referenced file in Finder' is not greyed. (thanks for the screen capture tip).

Comment: If it isn't greyed, then I can only assume that Photos still believes the original is external & wasn't imported. Presumably, clicking that option will produce the same error. (& most welcome:) You should have a 'Consolidate' option also available, that will ensure all external referenced items are imported - then all your external originals can safely be deleted afterwards.

Comment: I have all these files in a backup hard drive, I can copy these to my mac. How do I completely import these file into Photos so i don't have to have them in a directory as well as Photos app?http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257995/how-do-i-import-photos-in-to-the-photos-library-completely

Comment: The other linked QA now has the second part of this answer - that if that option hasn't always been checked then some are still externally referenced. Put those back where Photos expects them to be, then Consolidate will pull them into the Library & the externals can then be deleted. [adding to my answer for if someone find one question but not the other.]

Comment: Is there someway to get a list of missing photos from the photo library?